# Xcode Error: "The working directory does not exist"

Tags: c++, xcode

I started learning C++ using Xcode a few months ago and everything was going smoothly but I never saved anything. Then I had a fun idea for a side project using C++ but I had to save it somehow, so I made a new file and put it in my C++ desktop folder. Now when I try to run this file or any other file it warns me that "The working directory does not exist" and I automatically get a "Build Failed" error. How do I properly save new files to my working directory? And how do I fix this problem?

Comment: When you start Xcode, click on the "Create a new Xcode project", pick an appropriate project template, give your project a Product Name and change the Language to C++, navigate to Desktop and hit the New Folder button name it Projects.  A subfolder in Projects using your Product Name will be created.  Then drag your source files into your new project.

Comment: @Eljay I followed those steps but ran into two problems. First, there was no Language option for C++, only Swift and Objective C. Next, once I got to the end of your instructions, I was left at a settings page. I want to get to a page where I can build and run and save my work to a file. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which _appropriate project template_ did you select?  You should pick one of the ones that support C++.

Comment: @Eljay Which project template should I select for a basic C++ project? I did some Googling and couldn't find an answer. Thank you.

Comment: create new Xcode project > Command Line Tool template > change Language from Objective-C to C++